# Minecraft - Two servers, two subdomains, two ports, don't want to type in :port to connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

I have two minecraft servers, on sub-domains. www.server1.example.com and www.server2.example.com. server1 is port 25565, server2 is port 25566.

When users want to connect to a non-default port in minecraft, they have to specify www.server2.example.com:25566 to connect to the server. On the default port, this is not needed, they can simply connect via www.server1.example.com.

How can I pass along which port they're connecting to on the backside of things, so that users connecting to a non-standard port only have to type in the sub domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily for you, Minecraft uses [SRV records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) when looking up servers. This allows you to specify a port for each hostname. Simply create two different SRV records in your DNS zone with different hostnames and ports:

```
_minecraft._tcp.www.server1.example.com.  <TTL>  IN  SRV  <priority>  <weight>   25565   actual-host-server.example.com.
_minecraft._tcp.www.server2.example.com.  <TTL>  IN  SRV  <priority>  <weight>   25566   actual-host-server.example.com.
```

(Note: I haven't actually used SRV myself; this is based on another page on using SRV with Minecraft.)

Note that `actual-host-server.example.com` must have an `A` record; that is, it cannot be a `CNAME` alias for another domain name.

Comment: @Tillman32 Eh? I just picked out a random `*.no-ip.org` address and looked it up, and I got an A record, not a CNAME record. (A is what maps hostnames to IPs, after all.) Using such a name in the SRV record should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the forced-hosts of [bungeecord](http://www.spigotmc.org/threads/bungeecord.392/) if you'd be interested in using a proxy. I think Cnames might work, but I've not tried it